# How to get view object privilege for current user

Tags: oracle

I want to get view list for which the current user has select privilege. I understand that we cant get privilage details for views directly unlike tables. In case of tables I have view called 'ALL_TAB_PRIVS'.

How to get the list of view objects those are accessable for current user?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6):

The ALL_TAB_PRIVS view includes VIEWS in its result set.  In fact it includes all objects, so it will also show you procedures on which you have EXECUTE privileges.

Quite why it is called ALL_TAB+PRIVS rather than ALL_OBJ_PRIVS I don't know.  I agree it's confusing.  However it is correctly documented in [the Oracle Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2098.htm#sthref1475).

Incidentally, there is a view USER_TAB_PRIVS which shows you the privileges of the current user without having to restrict on GRANTEE.